# JOLT Transform multiple flat arrays into single nested array

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

I can't seem to figure out JOLT to the point of frustration..

I can bring all of the values into a single nested array with no issue, however I cannot add values to the root of the output.

**Data:**

```json
[
  {
    "Q": "10",
    "W": "0.5",
    "O": "Oregon",
    "Status": "Valid",
    "Type": "SSD",
    "Number": "Samsung1234",
    "Total": "50",
    "Category": "Drive"
  },
  {
    "Q": "15",
    "W": "0.5",
    "O": "Seattle",
    "Status": "Valid",
    "Type": "SSD",
    "Number": "PNY1234",
    "Total": "100",
    "Category": "Drive"
  }
  ...
]
```

**Current Spec:**

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "data.drives"
    }
  }
]
```

**Which gives me the following structure:**

```json
{
  "data" : {
    "drives" : [ {
      "Q" : "10",
      "W" : "0.5",
      "O" : "Oregon",
      "Status" : "Valid",
      "Type" : "SSD",
      "Number" : "Samsung1234",
      "Total" : "50",
      "Category" : "Drive"
    }, {
      "Q" : "15",
      "W" : "0.5",
      "O" : "Seattle",
      "Status" : "Valid",
      "Type" : "SSD",
      "Number" : "PNY1234",
      "Total" : "100",
      "Category" : "Drive"
    } ]
  }
 ...
}
```

What I need is:

```json
{
  "data": {
    "Number": "Samsung1234",
    "Category": "Drive",
    "Type": "SSD",
    "drives": [
      {
        "Q": "10",
        "W": "0.5",
        "O": "Oregon",
        "Status": "Valid",
        "Total": "50"
      },
      {
        "Q": "15",
        "W": "0.5",
        "O": "Seattle",
        "Status": "Valid",
        "Total": "100"
      }
    ]
  }
 ...
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Jolt remains mostly a mystery to me, I just can't wrap my head around it..

Comment: Do you only want to get the first Number, Category and Type ? I mean don't you want to return `PNY1234`, `Drive` and `SSD` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following transformation if the aim is to get the only the first `Number`, `Category` and `Type` values :

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "Number|Category|Type": "data.&",
        "*": "data.drives[&1].&" // all other attributes
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "cardinality",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "drives": "MANY", // keep this array as it is
        "*": "ONE" // bring only the first components 
                   // of the arrays respectively
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: I was hoping you would show up! I've read so many of your comments on here helping folks out with JOLT!

The shift works perfectly, however the cardinality removes all of the arrays except one. The "drives": "MANY" works but once the "*": "ONE" gets applied it removes them all.

Comment: Thank you @Grant  I think I could return exactly what you need to see, OK ?